# Equivalent tacit expressions

Tags: j, tacit-programming

I'm rather new to the J programming language and I have a question about equivalent tacit expressions in J.

I found two lines of J that were equivalent, but the conjunction in the code (`^:`)'s arguments were switched using the bracket operators.

I was mainly wondering how this expression:

```
u ^: x y
```

is equivalent to this expression:

```
x u @] ^: [ y
```

I would appreciate any J programmers to explain how the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the way to look at this is to look at the tacit expression `u@] ^: [` as a verb formed by the conjunction `^:` between the two verbs `u@]` and `[` . `u@]` is going to take the right argument `y` (to the exclusion of the left argument) and apply the monadic form of `u` to `y`. `[` is going to use the left argument `x` as the value that will provide the number of repetitions of `u` as an operator of `^:` .

For the explicit version, `u ^: x y` replaces the `[` and `]` verbs with their associated left and right arguments and since `x` is an operator of `^:` , `u ^: x` is effectively a monadic verb with `y` as its argument.

Let's set

```
   a=. 3
   b=. 4
   vb =. +: NB. double
   vb ^: a b
32
   a vb @] ^: [ b
32
   a (vb @] ^: [) b NB. expression within parenthesis is clearly a verb
32
```